# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/php error when trying to upload image

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get a simple uploading page up for images, but it gives me:
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/php

When I press upload it downloads the php script rather than run it.

My source I'm trying to learn from is: http://www.tipsntutorials.com/tutorials/PHP/67

I'm running off my local host right now. I'm really new at this so I'm not exactly sure what is going on here.

Here is my code:

**This is my html**

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Art Project FTW</title> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
<form name="upload" method="post" action="uploadresults.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  <input type="file" name="Image"><br>  
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image"> 
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**this is my php script**

```
<?php 
copy ($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['Image']['name']) or die ('Could not upload'); 
?>

<? echo $_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'] ?>
<img src="<?php echo $_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'] ?>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the path to a folder infront like `yourpath . $_FILES['Image']['name']`

yourpath has to be a string. Like try opening up my computer then going to localdisk C and adding a folder named "images" then you can easily do

```
<?php
    if (isset($_FILES['Image']))
        copy($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'],"C:\images/" . $_FILES['Image']['name']);
?>
```

because the second parameter of copy() is supposed to be the new path of where the image will be. Once you have all these in your folder, you can find them easily and make your montage or whatever else you're doing with your art project.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it to run my php. The problem now is:

    Warning: copy(a3.jpeg) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/uploadresults.php on line 2
Could not upload

I have to give write access somehow? I'm using apache, if that helps somehow.

Comment: @Richard can I see what you put?

Comment: I changed my PHP file to: <? echo $_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'] ?>
<img src="<?php echo $_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'] ?>"

But it won't go into effect because now I'm getting another error that I can't even save my own work in my root. I'm using Coda to write right now. http://www.imagebam.com/image/2df9b7143275154

Comment: And my project is to allow myself to upload an image and to create a mosaic out of it.

Comment: I got the write permissions to work. Okay so now I have...

`<?php 
copy ($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'], "opt/local/apache2/htdocs/".$_FILES['Image']['name']) or die ('Could not upload'); 
?>

<? echo $_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'] ?>
<br />
<img src="file://<?php echo $_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'] ?>" />`

but when I try to upload it gives:

Warning: copy(opt/local/apache2/htdocs/a3.jpeg) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/uploadresults.php on line 2
Could not upload

Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: You shouldn't need `file://` in the image source. Just `<?php echo "<img src='" . $_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'] . "'>"; ?>` And double check your path to make sure it's correct.

Comment: The error I have now is:


Warning: copy() [function.copy]: Filename cannot be empty in /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/uploadresults.php on line 2
Could not upload

. I'm not sure if it's looking in the right place. I'm trying to copy the temp image into my root which is _opt/local/apache2/htdocs_

I edited my php to:

`<?php 
copy ($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'], "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/".$_FILES['Image']['name']) or die ('Could not upload'); 
?>

<? echo $_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'] ?>
<img src="/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/" <?php echo $_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'] ?>" />`

Comment: take out the path in the image source. If you want to keep that there then you'll need to replace tmp_name with name because tmp_name is the actual image and name is the name of the image.